# How do you enable a disabled cipher OpenSSL

Tags: node.js, openssl

I am trying to use the ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384 cipher in node js.

All the node js code says is that you can select a cipher that is present in the `tls.getCiphers()` list.  This cipher is not present. It is also not present in the list of default ciphers seen using `openssl ciphers -V` (which matches the tls.getCiphers() list).

`openssl ciphers -V aNULL` shows the cipher present in OpenSSL but disabled.

According to the OpenSSL website, this can only be added to the list of enabled ciphers by recompiling OpenSSL.  I have the latest source code (3.0.0). I am assuming that you change the list of supported parameters by running the config script with a command line parameter, or changing a config file somewhere.

But I cannot find any reference as to where or how to do this.

Can someone please direct me to where this is documented?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: **the cipher(suite) is there**

The aNULL suites are compiled in all versions of OpenSSL, even 3.0.0, although they are *disabled* when using the default cipherlist. You don't need to recompile anything. (And since I doubt any nodejs package yet was built against OpenSSL 3.0 which was only released a few weeks ago, and I'm not even sure it's compatible, you don't want to try to use 3.0.) I don't know why `tls.getCiphers()` doesn't list them; I'll try to look into that later. (Even the *eNULL* suites are compiled, but are excluded not only from DEFAULT but also from ALL, and must be specified explicitly or as COMPLETEMENTOFALL, which is mathematically insane. OTOH ciphers that *claimed* confidentiality but are broken, like RC4 and 1DES, are not compiled with the 'standard' configuration.)

However, to use an ADH ciphersuite (including the one you named), you must:

- provide (temp)DH parameters. This is [documented for *DHE*](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/tls.html#tls_perfect_forward_secrecy) but the same also applies for ADH
- specify a cipherlist that includes at least the desired suite(s), AND for OpenSSL 1.1.0 up ALSO sets @SECLEVEL=0 (since the added-in-1.1.0 global security level defaults to 1 which disables ADH)

The following works for me:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const tls = require('tls');
const dhparam = fs.readFileSync("n:certx/dh1parm.pem");
var svr = tls.createServer({ciphers:"aNULL:@SECLEVEL=0",dhparam}, 
    (socket)=>{console.log("connected!\n")} );
svr.listen(9889);
```

Comment: Great answer; nice and short; and it worked first time for me.   I have no idea how I would found this without your reply.  Thanks

Comment: I needed to change the suite to "ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:@SECLEVEL=0" to prevent selection of TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA